# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease

Tags: flutter

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease I keep getting this error as I try building my flutter app, can I get some insights

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMslK.png)
I'm having a problem trying to build my app bundle,execution keeps failing from the flutter gradle build line

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean` on terminal and run again, please show screenshots of the error terminal and explain better